# Login form cant connect to database

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms

I cannot connect to my database, i receive message "invalid user or password " even if the password is correct, what should i do anyone any idea or my code is wrong here are all my code for login form/

here is my code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class LoginForm

  Private Sub UsersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UsersBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.UsersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet1)
End Sub

Private Sub LoginForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.users' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.UsersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.users)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database_topdent.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
  Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * from  users where User = @user and Password = @password ", connection)

  command.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserTextBox.Text
  command.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PasswordTextBox.Text

  Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
  Dim table As New DataTable()
  adapter.Fill(table)

  If table.Rows.Count() <= 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("username or textbox invalid")
  Else                   
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
  End If

End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, at the end of your SQL Statement, you might want to add `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` to make the password search case sensitive. Unless a case-insensitive password search is what you want.

Comment: Where in this code do you get a message?  You filled a table, but you never use it.

Comment: 1) I assume you already know that storing plain passwords is a very bad idea. 2) Change the SQL to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [users] WHERE [User] = @user AND [Password] = @password` and then you can use the [ExecuteScalar method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) to simply retrieve a number without all the messing about with a DataTable. 3) N.B. USER is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) so it should be escaped by enclosing it in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This is so confusing.
You need to check for the username and password, not just count the rows. And that table.rows.count "<=0" ? makes no sense to me.
I can see where you were going with it, but its wrong. And the question itself is not clarified enough. But assuming this is a login form. Try this>

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1_Click


            Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database_topdent.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * from  [users] where [User] = @1 and [Password] = @2 ", connection)

            connection.Open()

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", UserTextBox.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", PasswordTextBox.Text)

            Using dr As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

                Dim userFound As Boolean = False

                Dim Name As String = ""

                While dr.Read

                    userFound = True
                    Name = dr("User").ToString

                End While

                If userFound = True Then

                    MsgBox("Yes!")

                ElseIf userFound = False Then

                    MsgBox("nay")


                End If

            End Using

   connection.close()
    End Sub
```

Just make sure your columns are set to vchar. I'm not able to test it, but it should work.

First you need to open the connection. Then you need to read the data in your database with the reader. then, if username and password is found, present a msg or whatever you want.
I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but here I am playing a quick good samaritan.

**UPDATE #With permissions**
1. Add another column named "Permissions"
2. Create a Module.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1_Click


            Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database_topdent.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * from  [users] where [User] = @1 and [Password] = @2 ", connection)

            connection.Open()

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", UserTextBox.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", PasswordTextBox.Text)

            Using dr As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

                Dim userFound As Boolean = False



                While dr.Read

                    userFound = True
                    User1 = dr("User").ToString
                    Permissions = dr("Permissions").ToString

                End While

                If userFound = True Then

                    MsgBox("Yes!")

                ElseIf userFound = False Then

                    MsgBox("nay")


                End If

            End Using

   connection.close()
    End Sub
```

A module

```
Module Module1

Public User1 As String
Public Permissions As String

End Module
```

And then call stuff in your forms...
For example in your main form or wherever, if you have 2 buttons on load form you can do

```
If Permissions = "admin" then
Button1.enabled = true
else if Permissions = "user" then
msgbox(fu)
end if
```

Comment: thank you i have figured out . know i want to know how to make user and admin permissions ? example admin has full access but the user not ?? how to make that

Comment: @PsychoRealM If this post answered your question, accept it by giving it a check mark.  New questions should be new posts.

Comment: you need to add another column "permissions" oh so thats what you were trying to do with that table. you need to save the permissions, and create a module 'public Permissions as string'  'public User as string' And you can call those in your forms using IF 'if permissions = "admin" show this and that.

Comment: I updated the answer with the permissions if you need anything else, open a new question.

Comment: @Kohl please don't answer questions you find "confusing". If the Count is 0 or less then no records were returned thus the invalid. It is not wrong. Select Count is exactly what you need to know. No extraneous objects, less sensitive data sent over the wire. Use more descriptive parameter names. No need to "assume" login form. The title says it. Use Parameters.Add not .AddWithValue. "vchar" is not an SQL datatype. You just searched for user name why search again. Why set found=true without any check. None of that reader nonsense is necessary. A Module??

Comment: Thank you . know the login it works . but know i want to make permissions ? i have created the module but still doesnt work

Comment: Look at the updated login code in my answer. You need to remove the dim name as string, we need to store them globally. right click on your program - add -> module it will hold your login info for all forms. You create the dim user1 as public, dim permissions as public in the module, and you call them in your login form as user1 = dr("user1").tostring, permissions = dr("permissions").tostring

Comment: Hello my friend i have added ur code and i have created the module, know what code i have to enter and can u tell me please where i have to enter. it would be too nice..   i have created the 3rd column in users table and have named it permissions and know what to do ?

Comment: yes, but you're trying to check if it works in your login form in loginform_load event. Your logic should be "I login -> new form is shown - in the new form load event check for permissions" 2. You don't need to have your module under "import system.data.sqlclient" create a module outside your login form, it should be standing on its own, so you can call it from whatever form you want without writing the same code over and over. 3. in your login form after "userFound = true" you need to use your module strings. Permissions = dr("Permissions").tostring Compare my updated answer to your code.

Comment: Know im configuring it i will tell u, if i figured out or not.

Comment: I have figured it out brother,  i have created a module outside the login form/ and i have added  Permissions = dr("Permissions").ToString under  usersFound = True.. Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hello here are my code for login with admin/user it works, but know i want to make permission example when user is logged in not have full access , but the admin is full access..

Here are all my codes for ' Login_Form '

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
      Module Module1

Public User1 As String
Public Permissions As String


End Module
Public Class LoginForm
    Private Sub UsersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UsersBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.UsersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DataSet1)

End Sub

Private Sub LoginForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.users' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.UsersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.users)

    If Permissions = "admin" Then
        Button1.Enabled = True
    ElseIf Permissions = "user" Then
        Form1.RaportetToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database_topdent.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * from  [Table_login] where [Username] = @1 and [Password] = @2 ", connection)

    connection.Open()

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", UserTextBox.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", PasswordTextBox.Text)

    Using dr As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

        Dim userFound As Boolean = False

        Dim Name As String = ""

        While dr.Read

            userFound = True
            Name = dr("Username").ToString

        End While

        If userFound = True Then

            Form1.Show()


        ElseIf userFound = False Then

            MsgBox("Username or password is wrong!!!!!! ")


        End If

    End Using
    connection.Close()



    If Permissions = "user1" Then
        Form1.RaportetToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False

    End If




End Sub
```

End Class